# Javascript - shorten titles that are too long

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm learning javascript and on my wordpress blog I'm using it shorten really long titles.

```
<script>
    jQuery(".wlt_search_results h4 a").each(function() {
        if(jQuery(this).text().length > 30) {
            jQuery(this).text(jQuery(this).text().substr(0,80));
            jQuery(this).append('…..View More');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Is it possible to extend this so if a title is less than 30 characters it doesn't show the ....View More by default? I'm unsure how to implement this so any pointers would be very much appreicated.

Thanks! :)

Comment: Might be interesting to look into [CSS Ellipsis](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/).

Comment: jQuery(this).append('…..View More'); remove this line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code replace your code

```
if(jQuery(this).text().length > 30){
    jQuery(this).text(jQuery(this).text().substr(0,30)+'...View More');
}
```

My Result

[image]